# mongoose Handling two ref ObjectID in one field to fetch each collection of the ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm pretty new in mongoose and rest API, i have a problem to retrieve each collection refer to another doc

> All of this schema is edited to make it easy to read, as the real case i have more field that i think it's don't needed to show up

I have a `user schema` data like this:

```
{
    "_id": "123"
    "username": "Paijo",
    "email": "paijo@gmail.com"
}
{
    "_id": "345"
    "username": "Flix",
    "email": "Flix@gmail.com"
}
```

and i have `message schema` data like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5f525b2ac1267e868e882fbc",
    "roomId": "123_345",
    "latestMessage": "Bisa lahh cujkkkk",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-09-05T07:00:27.846Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-09-04T15:20:10.840Z"
    }
}
```

I want to query if there's some `user _id` in `roomId` and retrieve all field of `user schema` and `message schema`.

so let say i'm login with a `user _id` 123, i want to get message contain 123 in `roomId` and detail user of `345`,

the expected result i want to fetch is:

```
{
    "_id": "5f525b2ac1267e868e882fbc",
    "roomId": "123_345",
    "latestMessage": "Bisa lahh cujkkkk",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-09-05T07:00:27.846Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-09-04T15:20:10.840Z"
    },
    "username": "Flix", // get result from user schema which has _id 345
    "email": "Flix@gmail.com" // get result from user schema which has _id 345
}
```

currently i just can fetching all message contain an `_id` of user login with this query but i don't have an idea how to fetch detail user of another id in `roomId`

```
exports.listChat = async (req, res)=>{
  const userID = req.userID
  const listChat = await ChatRoom.find({roomId: new RegExp(userID)}).select("-message")
  console.log('listChat' , listChat)

  res.send(listChat)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) and defining two separate subfields: `me` (current user) and `other` - the value you want to use for [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html).

```
db.message.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            members: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { mem: { $split: [ "$roomId", "_" ] } },
                    in: {
                        me: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$$mem", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this", "123" ] } } }, 0 ] },
                        other: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$$mem", cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", "123" ] } } }, 0 ] },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "members.me": "123"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "user",
            localField: "members.other",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$user"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            roomId: 1,
            latestMessage: 1,
            updatedAt: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            username: "$user.username",
            email: "$user.email",
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MK_YMtJ02fM)

Comment: about your query, does `$project` is needed? i mean, i'd wanted to show all field instead of defined every field

Comment: @flix no, it's just to get rid of nested subdocument but you don't need it